# AsyncTask for updating widget - how to access textviews in onPostExecute()?

Tags: android, multithreading, widget, android-appwidget

Following situation:

I have an `app widget` which polls data from an url and updates the widget with the `parsed html`. On `pre-honeycomb` devices this can be done via a `service` without using a seperate thread. Now, on ICS, this has changed and an `ASyncThread` is necessary.

To access the `TextViews` in the `Widget-Updater-Service` I use

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView1,"test");
```

But this does not seem work in an `ASyncThread`. Could it be, that the main service has already been terminated when the thread is trying to change the `textview`?

Any ideas on solving this problem?

Comment: Note that you can use [StrictMode.ThreadPolicy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html) change the default behaviour on Android 3.0+, to keep allowing network operation running on UI thread.

Comment: can you provide some more code? I am using an AsyncTask to do something similar and may be able to help.

Comment: I cant comment directly since I'm a new user, but I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/HQYaJBAm

Comment: @yorkw Changing the policy did the trick, even hough this might be a terrible, terrible hack.

Comment: @skyworxx, I don't think it is a hack, it was the default behavior before API Level 10, and is modified since then by introducing this API.

Comment: @skyworxx, I have the same problem, if you solve this problem then please post here...!!!

Comment: I have posted the solution, @AndroidBoy

Answer (score 4):

Best to keep your own record of the RemoteView to be updated for each
appWidgetId so that your private internal BroadcastReceivers can
update it. You can use the AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget() at any
time not just when you get the ACTION_UPDATE intent.

Widget.java:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    ComponentName watchWidget;

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

    // onUpdate is called every xx seconds.
    // trigger fetch from the server!
    FetchTask fetchTask = new FetchTask();
    fetchTask.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    fetchTask.remoteViews = remoteViews;
    fetchTask.watchWidget = watchWidget;

    fetchTask.execute(PHONE_NUMBERSURL);
}
```

FetchTask.java:

```
class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<String>> {

    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        List<String> Sent = new ArrayList<String>();
        return Sent;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        if (appWidgetManager != null) {
            String finalString = "sync @";
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.sync_textView, finalString);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your method for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082315/using-json-to-match-a-string-with-todays-date but I keep getting a FC.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the widget should be consuming only data that is already processed and promptly available. Maybe you should call a service to prepare this data (through AsyncTask's) and when the all the work is done, the service should call `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget`. But that's just MHO.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following method to update your app widget:

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Comment: The problem is "remoteViews", i can't access it from an asyncthread

Answer (score -2):

Trying calling the .setText method in onpostexecute()

Comment: there is no "findvaluebyid"-method, so I can't use setText for updating a widget